# How to limit members code search to current document only?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I like new search feature but cant find option to limit that to current document only
Can someone please advise if this is doable?
Is there any option to search members in current doco / class ?

[image]

** EDIT **

Im looking for previous version:

[image]

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to filter the list, other than by file/type/member. It's a good idea though, so perhaps you could file a feature request. It's easy to do, via _Help | Send feedback | Request a feature_.

Comment: Gosh.... After upgrade this feature replaced previous search box where I was able to search with current document. Is there any option to return to previous?

Comment: @DrewNoakes This isn't a feature-request, it should be a _bug report_ given that the ability to restrict a search scope to the current file is now broken (or rather: removed) functionality. That's a _design bug_, imo.

Comment: Agree - this is sooo annoying - surprised noone rised that before me. Waiting fix - does anyone know any extenenstion what cad do the same?

Comment: Apologies, yes that's a bug report. I didn't realise the feature existed to scope down to the current document. For bugs, use _Help | Send feedback | Report a problem_ instead, and paste a link to the ticket here so that others can vote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems MS noticed that and fixed that with newest update - so problem fixed in `17.5.4`

Started happening again... Finally found option to disable it:

```
Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features > New Visual Studio Search Experience. After restarting, you will now be able to open the All-In-One Search either with your mouse or through keyboard shortcuts
```

Comment: Stooped working again... It seems work just after upgade to ANY version then after few restarts return to this weird window. I'll report bug with MS